# Adding email to new contact with JXA

Tags: automation, applescript, javascript-automation

I'm trying to create a contact using Javascript for Automation (JXA) but I haven't been able to figure out how to add an email address to the contact.

This is the code for adding the contact:

```
Contacts = Application('Contacts')
person = Contacts.Person().make()
person.firstName = "Tom"
person.lastName = "Tester"
Contacts.save()
```

That works as expected, i. e. it creates a contact with a first and last name.

I then tried to add this code to add an email address to the contact:

```
Contacts = Application('Contacts')
person = Contacts.Person().make()
person.firstName = "Tom"
person.lastName = "Tester"
email = Contacts.Email().make()
email.label = "Work"
email.value = "mail@test.de"
Contacts.add({ email, to: person })
Contacts.save()
```

The line `email = Contacts.Email().make()` gives the error "Can't make or move that element into that container."

I also tried `email = Contacts.ContactInfo().make()`, same error. Then I tried `email = Contacts.Email()`, which works, including assigning the two properties `label` and `value` thereafter, but then the line `Contacts.add({ email, to: person })` fails with the error "Can't convert types."

I'm pretty much stumped as to how this is supposed to work. None of the (very few) JXA code examples I could find were of any help in this particular case. I assume I'm getting some fundamental aspect of how this API is supposed to work wrong, but I just can't figure it out and the little documentation that's available hasn't helped either. Anybody have a clue how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer through trial and error, **no** thanks to Apple's documentation:

```
Contacts = Application('Contacts')
person = Contacts.Person().make()
person.firstName = "Tom"
person.lastName = "Tester"
email = Contacts.Email({ label: "Work", value: "mail@test.de" })
person.emails.push(email)
Contacts.save()
```

So I guess the "trick" is to create an object of the `Email` class while **not** using `make()`. Why you have to use `make()` when creating the Person and not when creating anything else is beyond me.

Comment: JXA is badly designed, crippled, and abandoned by Apple. You're much better off using AppleScript for application automation tasks—lousy language, but at least it does Apple events right and has a user community to help you when you get stuck. It's pretty easy to [call AppleScript handlers from other languages](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html) via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge, so you can still mix-and-match with `$language` of your choice.